# How to set the correct shebang for the needed Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, git, bash

I am running Ruby 2.0.0 with MacOS x.

For some reason, when I run `git push` on my local gitlab, I have a script that begins with

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
```

The Ruby version that is processed is `ruby1.8.7` which breaks the app.

How can I set correctly this shebang in order to use Ruby 2.0.0?

Comment: Specifically tell it to use ruby 2 wherever that may be?

Comment: @squiguy but how do I set thath ? Should I change the `shebang` ?

Comment: What does `which ruby` say? Are you using rvm to manage your ruby 2 install?

Comment: First, learn what `env ruby` is doing. Then, learn what `which ruby` is doing. Then replace the line with the correct value for the path to the Ruby you want.

Comment: @squiguy it outputs `ruby-2.0.0` but I was told that `git`, which runs this script, uses the first `ruby` it finds so `1.8.7`. I don't know how to set that. (Btw, yes I use rvm)

Comment: @theTinMan so I should use as `shebang` `/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby` ?

Comment: I think what you suggested should do.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, but removing the shebang and running `echo 2.0.0-p247 > .ruby-version` (substituting your specific version) might help. Or is the shebang absolutely necessary?

---

Scratch that, as per [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20131209015636/http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/using-rvm-on-the-shebang-line-in-a-script/) you could could try `#!/usr/bin/env rvm 2.0 do ruby` (or something similar).

Comment: dead link, fixed