# How to use shebang (#!) to use the correct Ruby version

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I'm using [Sensu](https://sensuapp.org/) to run checks on Sensu clients.

I'm getting this error, due to the Ruby version being less than 2.0:

```
 syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
```

I have Ruby 2.1.8 installed using RVM:

```
rvm use 2.1.8
Using /home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8
```

How can I force the interperter to use the correct version?

I tried using the shebang (`#!`) at the top of the file various ways:

1. `#!/home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8 ruby`
2. "[How to set the correct shebang for the needed Ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281457/how-change-correct-shebang-to-set-needed-ruby-version)" didn't work => `#!/usr/bin/env rvm 2.0 do ruby`
3. inside the script:

   ```
   source "/home/jenkins/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
   rvm use "2.1.8"
   ```

Any other suggestions?

**edit**
Thanks to @mudasobwa it's working when I run it from the jenkins user with 2.1.8

```
jenkins@chef-production2-backoffice01:~$ rvm use 2.1.8
Using /home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8
jenkins@chef-production2-backoffice01:~$ ruby check_disk_space.rb #works 
CheckDisk OK: All disk usage under 85% and inode usage under 85%
jenkins@chef-production2-backoffice01:~$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head
jenkins@chef-production2-backoffice01:~$ ruby check_disk_space.rb #doesn't work even though first row is #!/home/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/bin/ruby
check_disk_space.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
         short: '-t TYPE[,TYPE]',
               ^
check_disk_space.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
```

Another issue is that the program that runs the script is the sensu client with is ran with the known user `sensu`

`ps aux |grep sensu
sensu    13148  4.0  0.4  86512 18696 ?        Sl   09:38   0:00 /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/sensu/bin/sensu-client -b -c /etc/sensu/config.json ...`

Comment: Have you tried just `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`?

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the shebang line format. There should be the path to executable, as returned by `which ruby`.

So, the preferred way would be use this Ruby as the standard default:

```
rvm use 2.1.8 --default
```

This should be enough to run Ruby scripts using the chosen version of Ruby. If you are to select this version for this particular script, the easiest way to go would be to run `which ruby` after you switched the version with `rvm` and copy-paste the output of the above in shebang line:

```
$ which ruby
/home/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/bin/ruby # NB the output may differ
```

and now use it in shebang as is, without spaces:

```
#!/home/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/bin/ruby
```

Comment: hi @mudasobwa, thanks for the answer. it's not working . still same errors

Comment: What exactly did not work? Shebang or `rvm --default`?

Answer (score 0):

Shebang with rvm:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
```